# Controlling which nested resources serializer group context is applied

Tags: symfony, serialization, api-platform.com

I have four classes: MainEntity, SubEntityA, SubEntityB, and CommonMiniEntity.

MainEntity has a SubEntityA and SubEntityB property, and both SubEntityA and SubEntityB have a CommonMiniEntity property.

CommonMiniEntity has two properties where one uses the `normal` group and the other uses the `extend` group.

```
MainEntity
    SubEntityA
        CommonMiniEntity
            - propertyA #[Groups(['normal'])]
            - propertyB #[Groups(['extended'])]
    SubEntityB
        CommonMiniEntity
            - propertyA #[Groups(['normal'])]
            - propertyB #[Groups(['extended'])]
```

How can I instruct the serializer to only apply a given group to select sub-resources when serialized and deserialized?  For instance, serializing MainEntity with `normal` applied to both and `extended` only applied to SubEntityB should return the following:

```json
{
    "subEntityA" : {
        "propertyA": 111
    },
    "subEntityB" : {
        "propertyA": 222,
        "propertyB": 333
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom normalizers to do this and inject other normalizer like done in this example.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer/custom_normalizer.html

When you call the original normalizer, you can add some groups to the `$context` variable

Comment: Thanks Fabien,  I do something similar to allow/restrict properties based on a user's permission.  What is different with this is the groups are dependent upon which class is being processed and not external condition.  What would happen if SubEntityB was processed before SubEntityA?  I suppose I can try removing groups from context, but it is a bit funky.

Comment: I don't understant what you mean by `SubEntityB was processed before SubEntityA? `. If you need separate fields based on whether you are serialzing A or B , then you need to create groups for A and groups for B . Unless I'm missing something :)

Comment: Let's say I want to include `propertyB` (which is part of the `extended` group) only if is under `SubEntityB`.  My custom normalizer which happens to encounter `SubEntityB` first, does its job and adds `extended` to the `$context` variable.  But then later, its `SubEntityA`'s time to be serialized, and while the normalizer wouldn't attempt to added `extended`, wouldn't it still be in the `$context` variable?

Comment: The context is set on every object, so you can add groups per-object.